# Combine columns of Pivot Table in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that displays the Count of Items, the Avg. Sell Price, and Avg. Supplier Price. I need to find the difference between the Sell Price and Supplier Price and their percentage difference. I have tried using Calculated Fields, but they only work on an individual cell level. The data is organized as Purchaser, Item, Item Id, Sell Price, Supplier Price.

My table is as follows:

```
Row Labels (Item) | Count of Item Id | Avg of Sell Price | Avg of Supplier Price
    A             |         3        |        $2         |            $1.9
    B             |         4        |        $3         |            $3.25
```

I know the difference would be Avg. of Sell Price - Avg of Supplier Price, but you cannot subtract columns in a Pivot Table.

How does one perform this calculation?

Comment: Depending on your version of Excel, you may be able to add a calculated field from the Ribbon PivotTableAnalyze > Calculations > Fields, Items, & Sets.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I have tried Calculated Fields, but they only work on the cell level not the aggregate level.